# Deployment status shows me deploying more components than I am, why?

Tags: deployment

Ok so I'm deploying 3 components (updated Apex class, two updated custom fields) from Developer Pro Sandbox to our Full Copy Sandbox. While doing so, I see the following under Deployment Status:

[image: Four out of Three Deployed! Wow!]

So that seems a little bizarre to me! What's going on?!! When the deployment finishes successfully, it changes to the following (looks more normal):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Usually in that fraction, the denominator shows the number of components that are being deployed and the numerator shows the number of components being processed (during deployment).

Let's say, in your deployment there are two custom fields which are being deployed. The deployment process checks the existence of parent custom object for that two custom fields in the target Organization.

From the official Documentation of deployment dependencies:

> Metadata components may depend on other components. For example, you can’t deploy a custom field without deploying its custom object as well because the field's existence depends on the object. These kinds of object dependencies are not always within the same object; they can be across different objects. For example, a relationship field on one object can’t be deployed without the target object being included in the deployment, or already present in the target organization.

You can find the explanation in [Deployment Dependencies](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dev_lifecycle.meta/dev_lifecycle/migrate_risks.htm) and [Monitoring the Status of Your Deployments](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dev_lifecycle.meta/dev_lifecycle/migrate_monitor.htm) of Salesforce.